# How do I ignore an ApplicationListener defined in spring.factories?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm importing a Spring Boot Starter in my project because it contains a class I would like to use but I don't want auto configuration to run. I can see in the starter that there is a `META-INF/spring.factories` file which has both auto configurations as well as application listeners defined.

```
# Auto Configurations
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
    org.demo.SomeAutoConfiguration,\
    org.demo.AnotherAutoConfiguration

# Application Listeners
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=\
    org.demo.SomeApplicationListener,\
    org.demo.AnotherApplicationListener
```

I've figured out how to exclude specific classes from auto configuration and this works great.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={SomeAutoConfiguration.class, AnotherAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Now I can't seem to figure out how to exclude one or more of these application listeners. Any ideas?

Comment: Which Spring Boot starter are you referring to?

Comment: This is a custom starter, not one of the ones provided by Spring

Comment: If its your custom starter then you control exactly what auto-configuration and listeners you are providing.

Comment: This is a custom starter created by my organization but not one that I own. Basically there is a single ApplicationListener that I want to pull into my project but I don't want all the other auto configurations and application listeners to run because they don't apply to my project

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no built-in support for ignoring certain application listeners.
However, you could subclass `SpringApplication`, override `SpringApplication.setListeners(Collection<? extends ApplicationListener<?>>)` and filter out the listeners that you don't want:

```
    new SpringApplication(ExampleApplication.class) {

        @Override
        public void setListeners(Collection<? extends ApplicationListener<?>> listeners) {
            super.setListeners(listeners
                    .stream()
                    .filter((listener) -> !(listener instanceof UnwantedListener))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }

    }.run(args);
```